# How to join multiple columns with only one foreign key using linq

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

hello stackoverflow community, thats my first question on stack over flow. Thanks for help in advance.
Please help to join 2 tables where one table have list of specialties with thier ids as primary key and second table have 3 columns contains ids of specialties as foreign keys.

that's my code

```
var q = (from u in db.Providers
                         join v in db.PracticeSpeciality
                         on new { p1 = u.prSpecId1, p2 = u.prSpecId2, p3 = u.prSpecId3 }
                         equals new { p1 = v.pracSpecId, p2 = v.pracSpecId, p3 = v.pracSpecId }
                         where (u.prId == pc.stprId)
                         select new
                         {
                             u.prFname,
                             u.prLname,
                             u.prMI,
                             u.prTitle,
                             v.
                         }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: It would be better if you placed the code in the body of your question, rather than as a linked image. I doubt that anyone is going to take the time to rewrite your query - copy/paste ftw.

Comment: Upon further inspection of your code - what is the entity `pc` that you have referenced in the where clause? Perhaps this is part of the issue?

Comment: thanks for guidance @sleeyuen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return the data of specialists for a provider this will work.

```
var q = (from prov in providers
          join esp1 in praEspec on prov.prSpecId1 equals esp1.pracSpecId
          join esp2 in praEspec on prov.prSpecId2 equals esp2.pracSpecId
          join esp3 in praEspec on prov.prSpecId3 equals esp3.pracSpecId
          where prov.prId == pc.stprId
          select new
          {
             esp1,
             esp2,
             esp3
          }).FirstOrDefault();
```